# Does OL3 support Vector Tiles on WebGL?

Tags: webgl, openlayers-3

Does OpenLayers 3 support LineString and Polygon rendering on WebGL? I have set renderer to 'webgl' and tried to render a TopoJSON format Vector Tile but got the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: vectorSource.loadFeatures is not a function".

The following example from the OL3 web site only works if i remove the 'renderer' attribute from the map properties so the map is rendered using an HTML5 canvas:

     `var map = new ol.Map({
        renderer: 'webgl',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.VectorTile({
            source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
              attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
                html: '© Mapbox ' +
                    '© ' +
                    'OpenStreetMap contributors'
              })],
              format: new ol.format.MVT(),
              tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 22}),
              tilePixelRatio: 16,
              url: 'http://{a-d}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v6/' +
                  '{z}/{x}/{y}.vector.pbf?access_token=' + key
            })
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });`

Comment: Have you checked the [github wiki entry](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/wiki/Vector-Data-Representation-for-WebGL) on this?

Comment: Also add some sample code.

Comment: And run your code against `ol-debug.js` (instead of the minified `ol.js`), which gives you more readable error messages

Comment: @rbaleksandar That info was written on Feb 5, 2013 and seems to be a preliminary design document.

Comment: @rbaleksandar sample added.

Comment: @Sidney Gijzen I updated the question with the debug version error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Only the canvas renderer supports vector tiles with `ol.layer.VectorTile`.

Comment: Thanks. There is any LineString rendering support on WebGL? Is it planned to WebGL support for vector tiles?

Comment: Are there any examples of webgl with line and polygon features in 3.2x?

Comment: Webgl Polygon support was added in Openlayers 3.20 - I still get same error. Will vector tiles work with webgl render in future ?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, only points are currently supported for WebGL rendering, but there certainly appears to be a desire to expand this out to lines and polygons. With the VectorTile support (granted canvas only) already being there, I couldn't imagine them not including full WebGL.

There was a code sprint last year where they did a proof of concept. There were a number of limitations, but it proved it was possible.
http://www.camptocamp.com/en/actualite/openlayers-3-towards-drawing-lines-and-polygons-with-webgl/

Answer (score 0):

```
renderer    ol.renderer.Type | Array.<ol.renderer.Type> | undefined
```

Renderer. By default, Canvas and WebGL renderers are tested for support in that order, and the first supported used. Specify a ol.renderer.Type here to use a specific renderer. Note that the Canvas renderer fully supports vector data, but WebGL can only render Point geometries.

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html